# Sqoop export doesn't handle utf-8 characters

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, netezza, sqoop

I am trying to use Sqoop Export to Export Data from **HDFS** to **Netezza** table. And I am facing issue with few of french characters. 
I have table with just only one column and one row as mentioned below.

> En fil métallique résistant mâchouillag

- I am able to see this text without any issue in Hive Table and corresponding HDFS directory as well.
- I am also able to insert this same line in Netezza table without any issue, so I know my Netezza database handles these character.

**Problem:**
When I use sqoop to export these data to Netezza table, I get following row as compared to mentioned above.

> En fil meÌtallique rÃ©sistant maÌchouillag

It seems like there is any issue with the Netezza JDBC driver I am using to export, I should specify somewhere the encoding or something like that. However, I am not sure.

Could someone please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the character encoding used by the Netezza DB and/or table and/or column? That looks like an UTF-8 string forced (in binary format) into an ISO string.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter netezza encoding is `UTF8`. I could manually enter the string in this table without any issue, the issue happens only when I use sqoop export.